# Is there any option for HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using hadoop and in hadoop I am performing i/o operations with HDFS. but, It takes much time to process data in HDFS. Isthere any option to make processing faster and option for HDFS like MongoDB or any other options?

I am processing knowledge base for website categorization and It includes words,count of words and It includes about 1L lines with 50 categories so about 50L lines to process and search operation on it which is line by line in hdfs and takes much time.

Comment: Please add more details to your questions. What type of data you are dealing with, what's the size of your data. What's is the statistics of the time required.

Comment: Rahul, If there is huge document and want search from that document. It does line by line in HDFS. which takes too much time. Is there any option for fast search in BIG file?

Comment: I guess here you need to optimise your Hadoop installation. Have you tried using Cloudera Impala ? Project like Impala, HDFS2 are aim to improve Hadoop performance. If you are facing performance issue then try using these projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think HDFS2 means hadoop-2 using yarn architecture you will get a goood performance, also processing time for a big file depends upon various factor like your cluster configuration and data bandwidth between nodes.